# Incremental offset in Api call

Tags: javascript, api, while-loop, pagination, offset

I need to obtain all results when calling an api. I'm only getting 100. 
I know I have to offset every 100 to obtain all. Don't know how much results are in total.
I guess I should use "while" till the api says there is no more results.. or something like that...but I'm a total beginner in javascript so I don't know where is convenient to put it and how to implement it.
I'm using Google App Scripts to insert results in a Google Sheet.
I tried using a "while" function but i don't know if it is the right place to implement it.. and if variables are ok or not. See the //Loop comment
This is my code:

```
var APIurl = 'http://api.elit.com.ar/productos?offset=';
var offset = 0

function callAPI() {
  //Access Data
 var token = Utilities.base64Encode('mytoken');

  var auth =  {
    user_id: 'myid',
    token: token,}    

  var options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: 'POST',
    payload: JSON.stringify(auth),
    }

  // Call API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(APIurl, options);

  //Parse response
  var json= response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json)
}  

function displayData(){

  var data = callAPI();
  var results = data["resultado"];
  var output = []

  results.forEach(function(elem,i) {
  output.push([elem["cod_alfa"],elem["detalle"],elem["precio"]]);
  });

  //Loop
  while (results !== null){
  callAPI(APIurl + offset + 100);
  };

  //Clear previous content
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('mygooglesheeturl').getSheetByName('sheetname');
  ss.getRange(1,1,500,3).clearContent();

  //Insert new data in sheet
  var len = output.length;
  ss.getRange(1,1,len,3).setValues(output);
  Logger.log(output);


}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation? It should say how to do pagination.

Comment: It probably goes in the payload.

Comment: @Barman here is the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=15qwCNqWuW1Etl_z4ML4i0Y6Bga5UH2rB   is a PDF in spanish, if you need translation please ask me. It says that Pagination is done by writing "?offset=[number]" at the end of the url. So i have to find a way to implement that in the code to make it automatically paginate every 100 results and then print them all in the google sheet. Or print them 100 by 100, till complete all results.

Comment: I don't speak Spanish. :(

Comment: Look at the section titled Paginación

Comment: @Barman yes but how can i implement it to make it incremental? every 100 results, print it in the sheet...or collect the total results (don't know how much they are) and then print them all

Comment: Fetch your data in a loop until you get a result with less than 100 items. Start with &offset=0&limit=100, and add 100 to the offset each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barman yes i understand the concept but don't know the practical thing... can you show me how?

Comment: What's so difficult? Put the offset in a variable, concatenate the variable into the URL. Then add 100 to the variable before the next time.

Comment: @Barman the difficulty is that i'm learning javascript and don't know how to solve it.. that's why i'm here

Comment: @Barman i edited the question with what i've tried at the moment...I didn't put it before because it throws me error...I've also looked in google but no luck. I'm trying my best, really.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the URL as an argument to `callAPI()`, but the function doesn't use the parameter.

```
function callAPI(url) {
  //Access Data
 var token = Utilities.base64Encode('mytoken');

  var auth =  {
    user_id: 'myid',
    token: token,}    

  var options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: 'POST',
    payload: JSON.stringify(auth),
    }

  // Call API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  //Parse response
  var json= response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json)
}
```

You're not updating the `offset` variable. `offset` is always `0`, so `offset + 100` is always `100`. And you're not using the value returned by `callAPI()`. The loop needs to be before you push everything into the `output` array, or you can do that inside the `while` loop.

```
function displayData(){

  var output = []
  var offset = 0

  while (true) {
    var results = callAPI(APIUrl + offset).resultado;
    results.forEach(obj => output.push([obj.code_alfa, obj.detalle, obj.precio]);
    if (result.length < 100) {
      break;
    }
    offset += 100;
  }


  //Clear previous content
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('mygooglesheeturl').getSheetByName('sheetname');
  ss.getRange(1,1,500,3).clearContent();

  //Insert new data in sheet
  var len = output.length;
  ss.getRange(1,1,len,3).setValues(output);
  Logger.log(output);


}
```

Comment: Many Thanks! Now i'm having error with the line: `results.forEach(({code_alfa, detalle, precio}) => output.push([code_alfa, detalle, precio]);` It says **":" missing after property ID**. So I tried the code i was using before for that part. But then throws **TypeError can't find forEach function in the object [object Object]**

Comment: This is ES6 object shorthand. You can use Babel to transpile it if the syntax isn't supported.

Comment: I forgot to access the `resultado` property to get the list of results.

Comment: many thanks! i will post the code with all corrections working ok

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barman, this is the working code:

```
    var url = 'http://YOUR_URL?offset=';

function callAPI(url) {
  //Access Data
 var token = Utilities.base64Encode('YOUR_TOKEN');

  var auth =  {
    user_id: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
    token: token,}    

  var options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: 'POST',
    payload: JSON.stringify(auth),
    }

  // Call API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  //Parse response
  var json= response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);

}  


function displayData(){

  var output = []
  var offset = 0

  while (true) {
    var results = callAPI(url + offset).resultado;

    results.forEach(function (obj) {
    return output.push([obj.cod_alfa, obj.partnumber, obj.detalle, obj.precio, obj.iva, obj.marca, obj.rubro, obj.subrubro, obj.cotizacion, obj.stock, obj.peso, obj.link]);
    }); //REPLACE obj.YOUR_DATA

    if (results.length < 100) {
      break;
    }
    offset += 100;
  }



  //Clear previous content
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('YOUR_GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_URL').getSheetByName('YOUR_SHEET_NAME');
  ss.getRange(4,1,2000,12).clearContent();

  //Insert new data in sheet
  var len = output.length;
  ss.getRange(4,1,len,12).setValues(output);
  Logger.log(output);
}
```